# Why can't I assign a Javascript object to a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, object, dom

This is my code:

```
<input id="input_with_id" type="text" value="hello" disabled>
<script type="text/javascript">
     input_with_id = {type:"checkbox", value:"bye", disabled:false}
</script>
```

IE 8 shows me this error message: "This object does not manage this property or this method". But if I use this code, it works like it should:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var my_var = new Object();
     my_var = {a:"x", b:"y", c:"z"}
</script>
```

The only difference between these two codes is that in I'm trying to reassign a DOM element to a Javascript object which has the same structure as a DOM element and in the other one I'm reassigning a Javascript object to another Javascript object. Why can't you treat the DOM element like a Javascript object here although normally they work similarly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

Comment: What method are you trying to use? JS objects do not have an DOM counterpart per-se. Maybe you're omitting additional info on some plugins you might be using to create DOM elements from JS objects? Anyway, you're missing a `var` statement which may cause hiccups on IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var my_var = new Object(); my_var = {...};` is not exactly "normal" either. You're creating a completely *new* object and throwing away the first one that you created with `new Object`.

IE8 just doesn't like you "throwing away" a DOM element.

To put it simply, you're getting an error message because you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Yup, with each `my_var = `  you're **overwriting** `my_var`

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to use the "Auto Global" (referencing an element by its ID or Name) isn't recommended. (dealing with naming collisions is a pain point)

In addition, IE8 (and below) in particular do not allow you to change the `type` or `name`(IE7-) attributes dynamically (they were considered read-only)

In your case, if you want to manipulate the field, just use regular JavaScript (or your favorite JS library)

e.g.

```
<script>
  var myElem = document.getElementbyId('input_with_id');
  myElem.type = 'checkbox';
  myElem.value = 'bye';
  myElem.disabled = false;
</script>
```

(keeping in mind that this still won't work in IE8 due to the type attribute being read-only - *(it was fixed in IE9 (when running in Standards Mode))*)

Comment: The `type` attribute is only read-only if the element has been attached to the document. You can freely set `.type` *before* appending the element to the page.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol correct... in this case the element *was* added to the DOM (or I can only presume it was) thus it would be read-only in IE8. :-(